# What's wrong with my experiment?(young's double slit experiment with detectors)

Tags: double-slit-experiment, home-experiment

[How can I observe the photons in the double slit experiment?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285363/how-can-i-observe-the-photons-in-the-double-slit-experiment)
<-In my previous question, I asked if putting a differently directed polarizing filter(horizontal/vertical) on each slit while conducting the double slit experiment would collapse the wave, which would result in me seeing two bands of light on the screen. I was responded 'yes'(I think I was), so I tried the experiment today!

The interference pattern disappeared(I'm suspecting that was just because the light got weaker while going through the polarizers, it probably just became hazier). But the light was still diffracted; I could see a hazy horizontal line on the screen, not two vertical lines. That means that the light still has its wave nature, doesn't it?

Can you give a guess why this result happened? Could there be any mistakes? Or is the idea of placing polarizers to collapse the wave wrong in the first place?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EnABJ31Ax4
(I followed the directions of this video when I conducted the experiment.)